# Converting a std::wstring to int

Tags: c++, c++11

I presume this to be very simple but I cannot get it to work.

I am simply trying to convert a std::wstring to an int.

I have tried two methods so far.

The first is to use the "C" method with "atoi" like so:

```
int ConvertedInteger = atoi(OrigWString.c_str());
```

However, VC++ 2013 tells me:

**Error, argument of type "const wchar_t *" is incompatable with parameter of type "const char_t *"**

So my second method was to use this, per Google search:

```
std::wistringstream win(L"10");
            int ConvertedInteger;
            if (win >> ConvertedInteger && win.eof())
            {
                // The eof ensures all stream was processed and
                // prevents acccepting "10abc" as valid ints.
            }
```

However VC++ 2013 tells me this:

**"Error: incomplete type not allowed."**

What am I doing wrong here?

Is there a better way to convert a std::wstring to int and back?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you `#include <sstream>`? Your code with the stringstream should work.

Comment: Please try to convert string using `int ConvertedInteger = _wtoi(OrigWString);`...

Comment: You could always construct a `std::string` from the string and use `std::stoi` on that. You might incur a memory allocation if the number is big enough, but I doubt it's any worse than using stringstreams.

Comment: also I think `#include <istream>` is required for `wistringstream`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

No need to revert to C api (`atoi`), or non portable API (`_wtoi`), or complex solution (`wstringstream`) because there are already simple, standard APIs to do this kind of conversion : `std::stoi` and `std::to_wstring`.

```
#include <string>

std::wstring ws = L"456";
int i = std::stoi(ws); // convert to int
std::wstring ws2 = std::to_wstring(i); // and back to wstring
```

Comment: One reason to avoid using `sto*()` functions family is because they all throw exceptions. `ato*()` don't

Answer (score -1):

you can use available API from `wstring.h`.

to convert `WString` to `int` try `int ConvertedInteger = _wtoi(OrigWString);`.

for reference use msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa273408(v=vs.60).aspx.

Comment: What do you mean by *stream returns the string values*? The OP's [code works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c17228c41560b000), the error is elsewhere.

Comment: @Praetorian I mean that when we write/ read data to/ from stream object it works on string values in OP case it is wstring

Comment: The OP is using `wistringstream` which deals with `wchar_t`s, not `char`s. Once again, his code works, look at the link in my previous comment. The error message about using an incomplete type most likely means he forgot to include some header file.